# How to open modal window in div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, window, bootstrap-modal, modal-window

I use Bootstrap, how I can open modal window in `div` area under my buttons?

I would like to achieve an effect similar to the "Values" on page [initiative.com](http://initiative.com)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please improve your question for clarity: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Also, I don't see any modal dialogs in the link you provided.

Comment: I would like to get the effect of the layer, as on this page when you click on the link: FAST, BRAVE, DECISNE, SIMPLE

Comment: Inspecting the DOM on the example page you provided, those animations do not appear in a modal dialog.